# Does DOJO have a method of listening similar to .ajaxComplete() for when several AJAX calls are completed or successful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo

I am looking for a DOJO function that runs changes when code is complete similar to this function below:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   // run changes here
});
```

I have tried:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
   // run changes here
});
```

However, I am losing my changes still when there is a DOJO AJAX call. I am not trying to make an AJAX call just to listen for a completed one.

Comment: What version of dojo are you using ? You can use dojo/request/notify on dojo 1.7+. Otherwise, use dojo.xhrGet's load callback. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/xhrGet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative to ajaxComplete in Dojo is listening to "done" event of dojo/request/notify module

```
notify("done", function(responseOrError){
    // Do something whether a request has succeeded or failed
    if(responseOrError instanceof Error){
        // Do something when a request has failed
    }else{
        // Do something when a request has succeeded
    }
});
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/notify.html for more details.